# I have 4TB hard drive, how to use it under both OSX, windows and linux?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, hard-drive, mac

How to format it so that it can be used in Ubuntu, windows and OSX?

`Fat32`? I have rull out `NTFS` as an option.

Comment: @Run5k However no conclusion have been reached.

Comment: Agreed, but it is a rather subjective question so you probably won't reach a definitive conclusion. Assuming you are talking about external USB drives, I think **exFAT** would be the best. It has native read/write capabilities within both Windows & macOS, and currently those operating systems are prevalent in over 98% of the desktop/laptop computers in the world. For the other two percent using Linux, the [procedure to configure those machines to utilize exFAT](https://www.howtogeek.com/235655/how-to-mount-and-use-an-exfat-drive-on-linux/) with full read-write support is relatively simple.